# Jersey: subresource locator method will ignore @Produces annotation if an exception is thrown while excuting the delegation method

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

Jersey: subresource locator method will ignore @Produces annotation if an exception is thrown while excuting the delegation method.
Example:

```
@Path("resource")
public class resource{ 
   @Path("a")
   @Produces("application/json")
   public Subresource subresourceDelegation(){
        throw new RuntimeException()
   }
}
```

Now the exception mapper generates the response but the media type will not set to application/json rather to application/octet-stream, which is the default media type.

Can anybody help me

Answer (score 0):

use `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` instead of @Produces("application/json")

Comment: Both ways have the same effect. Javadoc:  https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.23.2/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/MediaType.html#APPLICATION_JSON

Comment: I apologize for not checking jersey doc. as i was using  MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, I dont think you can throw exception and expect Producer to convert it to JSON format. Instead you can write an Exception Mapper in jersey and Handled this exception and return Response status as required in JSON format